# Controlling a Windows Service from a WPF app

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await, mvvm, timeout

I have a WPF Control Panel app, where I'm trying to stay close to an MVVM architecture. The control panel (the "the CP") is for a WCF service ("the Scheduler"), hosted in a Windows Service ("the Host"). My main concern, and topic for review here, is how I am avoiding blocking the CP responsiveness for too long. The Host control operations sometimes take longer than 3 seconds, which is long for a UI.

Because the start and stop methods are typed `void`, and I have been advised to steer well clear of using `async void` methods, instead I use a method I derived from an example somewhere:

```
private void ExecuteWithTimeout(Action task, int? timeout = null)
{
    timeout = timeout ?? HostServiceConstants.ServiceControlTimeout;
    var source = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var timedTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(task, source.Token).ContinueWith((t) =>
        {
            if (t.Exception != null)
            {
                t.Exception.Handle(ex =>
                    {
                        var frame = new StackFrame(1);
                        var methodName = frame.GetMethod().Name;
                        _logger.Warn("'ExecuteWithTimeout' exception from: '{0}': {1}", methodName, ex.Message);
                        return true;
                    });
            }
        });
    bool done = timedTask.Wait(timeout.Value);
    if (!done)
    {
        source.Cancel();
        var frame = new StackFrame(1);
        var methodName = frame.GetMethod().Name;
        _logger.Warn("'{0}' timed out after {1} milliseconds.", methodName, timeout);
    }
}
```

This is called from the viewmodel, when a `Command` is invoked from the view:

```
void ExecuteStartHostCommand()
{
    Exception exception = null;
    ExecuteWithTimeout(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                _host.Start();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                exception = ex;
            }
        });
    if (exception != null)
    {
        _logger.Error("Exception caught while trying to execute 'StartHostCommand': " + exception.Message, exception);
        if (exception is HostServiceException)
        {
            MessageBoxFacility.ServiceControlError((HostServiceException)exception);
        }
        else
        {
            throw exception;
        }
    }
}
```

Here, `_host.Start()` is a call to the model, which in turn uses a `System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController` to start the Host. My logging is showing such calls time out quite often, after 3000ms, but then said logging goes on to sow that the Host stopped anyway, as expected. I would like to avoid the kludgy looking `ExecuteWithTimeout` and rather use `await`, but that would involved using some `async void` methods, which I have been advised to avoid.

The code I have shown here is still quite experimental, and I have little experience controlling long running tasks so many steps away from the UI, so please ignore smaller  discrepancies etc.

Answer (score 4):

`async void` methods should generally be avoided, yes, but this looks like it's [one of the cases where they make sense](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16849019/41071).

---

```
var frame = new StackFrame(1);
var methodName = frame.GetMethod().Name;
_logger.Warn("'ExecuteWithTimeout' exception from: '{0}': {1}", methodName, ex.Message);
```

I don't see how is `methodName` useful here, it's always going to be `Handle`.

---

```
var frame = new StackFrame(1);
var methodName = frame.GetMethod().Name;
_logger.Warn("'{0}' timed out after {1} milliseconds.", methodName, timeout);
```

I think `[CallerMemberName]` would be simpler here.

---

```
throw exception;
```

This means that the stack trace of the exception is going to be rewritten. If you don't want to wrap the exception in another exception, you can use [`ExceptionDispatchInfo`](http://thorarin.net/blog/post/2013/02/21/Preserving-Stack-Trace.aspx) to preserve the stack.